# Database upgrade from odoo 9.0 to 10.0 - unmet dependencies errors

Tags: odoo, database-migration, odoo-10, odoo-9

I used the OpenUpgrade migrate.py script and successfully upgraded a 9.0 database to 10.0 but when I run my new migrated database on odoo 10.0 I get errors like this (about 50+):

```
ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module account_cancel: Unmet dependencies: account
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module rating: Unmet dependencies: mail
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module product_extended: Unmet dependencies: mrp, stock_account
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module pos_restaurant: Unmet dependencies: point_of_sale
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module website_mass_mailing: Unmet dependencies: mass_mailing
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module website_issue: Unmet dependencies: website_form, project_issue
2018-12-06 04:40:05,744 6828 ERROR db-9.0_migrated odoo.modules.graph: module sale_mrp: Unmet dependencies: mrp, sale_stock
```

etc.

I tested odoo 10.0 with a new database and it works fine. I'm just getting errors when I use my migrated database. It still allows me to try and login but then I get these errors.

[http://localhost:8069/web/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAmJA.png)

I am quite lost and new to odoo. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: it seems a problem in the website module, (not found), can you take a picture of your configuration file ?

Comment: Can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the addons-path in your configuration file is wrong.